# Why arrow function is not working in chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension's content script following code is not working:

```js
var myFunction = () => {
  console.log("sending msg");
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "myAction" });
}
```

But when I convert the arrow function to classic JS function it worked.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log("sending msg");
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "myAction" });
}
```

Why arrow function is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Probably a dupe: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a hoisting issue. A regular function call can be anywhere in the code while `const myFunction = ...` is only callable after its declaration.

Example of working code:

```js
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  console.log('Yay');
}
```

Example of failing code:

```js
myFunction(); // TypeError, myFunction is undefined at this point

var myFunction = () => console.log('Yay');
```

Comment: Based on what little is in the question, this is the best guess I can think of.

Comment: It worked. I called the function in two places. One of them is before the declaration which creates the error. Thanks.